VSCode - TypeScript template "cannot find name <element>
Update 1: I've noticed that the error only applies to the first .tsx file that has been opened in VSCode. Whichever file is opened first, IntelliSense runs and then the error is displayed. All other files works fine.
I did a fresh install of VSCode and Node. I then run  npx create-react-app my-app-test --template typescript.
Older projects that have worked in the past (2 weeks ago) also have this error which was not present before.
Sometimes it works, but the issue persists when I create a new file. Reloading VSCode does not fix the problem and the error returns to the previously ok file.
When the code is compiled, there are no errors. However I get the following error in vscode.
Cannot find name 'div'.ts(2304)
What its supposed to be
What Ive tried:

reinstall vscode, node, npm
changed typescript versions in vscode
different directories on PC
npm cache clean
run vscode without extensions

Versions:

tsc -v ->  Version 5.4.4
node -v -> v20.12.1
vscode -> 1.88
vscode tsc -> 5.4.3
OS-> W10

tsconfig
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}


package.json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.14",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.94",
    "axios": "^1.6.8",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.3",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.74",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.24",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}




Please show the first line of your function declaration

Could you also try adding import React from 'react'; at the top of your file.

You need the type declaration.
Run:
npm install -D @types/react @types/react-dom

or the equivalent in your prefered package manager

I've tried this but it doesn't work. I added some new details to my post.

If you could share a reproduction repo, I'll have a look
